# Parsing bencode string with Parsec

Tags: haskell, parsec

I'm trying to use Parsec to parse bencode strings. The format is 3:abc (number of characters, :, actual string).

I am given the following Parsec functions:

```haskell
char :: Char -> Parser Char
char c = satisfies (== c) ("character " ++ show c)

-- | Chain two parses, discarding the value of the first parser
pThen :: Parser a -> Parser b -> Parser b
pThen pa pb = parser inner
  where
    inner input =
      case runParser pa input of
        Success (_, rest) -> runParser pb rest
        Error err -> Error err

-- | Chain two parsers, feeding both the result and the remaining input from the first parser to the second parser.
with :: Parser a -> (a -> Parser b) -> Parser b
with pa f = parser inner
  where
    inner input =
      case runParser pa input of
        Success (a, rest) ->
          case runParser (f a) rest of
            Success (b, remaining) -> success b remaining
            Error err -> Error err
        Error err -> Error err

-- | Parse a number
number :: Parser Int
number = pMap read (some digit) `expecting` "number"

-- | Parser that consumes a fixed number of characters.
take :: Int -> Parser String
take nr = parser $ \input ->
  uncurry success (L.splitAt nr input)
```

The function signature is string :: Parser String

I tried doing it like this:
`string = P.with P.number (P.pThen P.char ':' P.take)`, with the idea being thet I take the integer returned by P.number, process and discard the :, then feed the integer into P.take to consume the required number of characters. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the problem you're currently having?  Perhaps you can post the error or failing test

Comment: I think you are doing a little bit of overengineering. This should work: `benCodeParser = do  {i <- many1 digit; char ':' ; count (read i) letter} `  (note, no compiler at hand, but you get the idea)

Answer (score 0):

Note that this isn't `parsec`.  This is some weird homebrew parsing library.  I gather this is homework and your professor has provided a set of parsing primitives for you to use?  A bunch of definitions seem to be missing (e.g., the definition of `Parser` itself, plus `satisfies`, `pMap`, etc.), but I think I can guess what they do.

Your attempt:

```
string = P.with P.number (P.pThen P.char ':' P.take)
```

has all the right components, but the expression `P.pThen P.char ':' P.take` is pretty broken.  It's passing three arguments to `pThen`, which only takes two.  You want some parentheses in there:

```
P.pThen (P.char ':') P.take
```

This still isn't going to work because `P.take` needs an integer argument.  You can't just hope that `p.with` will magically know where to supply it, so you'll want something explicit like:

```
P.pThen (P.char ':') (P.take n)
```

You want to use this expression with `P.with`, something like:

```
P.with P.number (... P.pThen (P.char ':') (P.take n) ...)
```

but you want the part in parenthesis to be a function that takes the argument supplied by `P.with` from the `P.number` parser and binds that to variable `n` so it can be passed to `P.take`.  You can do this with a lambda expression, so the following should work:

```
string = P.with P.number (\n -> P.pThen (P.char ':') (P.take n))
```

As an alternative syntax that does exactly the same thing, `P.pThen` can be surrounded by backticks and used as binary "operator", like so:

```
string = P.with P.number (\n -> P.char ':' `P.pThen` P.take n)
```

The name of the `pThen` function has been chosen to make this syntax look nice -- "first parse this, `pThen` parse that".